# Run postgres function with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
User.select("id, first_name, test(id)").where(id: [1,2,3,4,42]).within(50, :origin => [24.0, 75.5])
```

here test is a db function which takes user_id and within chain method is of geokit-rails gem

It is throwing error

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)

Any idea about it? Normally test function works with raw sql and I want to calculate near points (within range) so I need the within chain method thaats why dont want to use raw sql

Comment: I don't understand what is `test(id)` in `select` call. Can you provide some info of what this function does.

Comment: test is db function by `create function test (user_id integer)` in postgresql db

Comment: May be take a look at this gem https://github.com/norman/squirm_rails. You should wrap your custom select with procedure and call it. It should return you a valid relation.

Comment: It seems to be very old